# InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_56' with dtype float

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I am a newbie in Tensorflow and trying out the code on linear Regression given below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

boston=load_boston()
type(boston)
boston.feature_names

bd=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)

bd['Price']=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.target)
np.random.shuffle(bd.values)


W=tf.Variable(0.0)
b=tf.Variable(0.0)
#print(bd.shape[1])

tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W)
tf.summary.histogram('Biases', b)



dataset_input=bd.iloc[:, 0 : bd.shape[1]-1];
#dataset_input.head(2)

dataset_output=bd.iloc[:, bd.shape[1]-1]
dataset_output=dataset_output.values
dataset_output=dataset_output.reshape((bd.shape[0],1)) #converted (506,) to (506,1) because in pandas 
    #the shape was not changing and it was needed later in feed_dict


dataset_input=dataset_input.values  #only dataset_input is in DataFrame form and converting it into np.ndarray


X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,bd.shape[1]-1))
Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

Y_=W*X+b

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)


loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_-Y))
tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)



wb_=[]
with tf.Session() as sess:
        summary_merge = tf.summary.merge_all()

        writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("Users/ajay/Documents",sess.graph)

        epochs=10
        sess.run(init)

        for i in range(epochs):
            s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
            sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})

            sess.run(loss)
            writer.add_summary(s_mer,i)

            #tf.summary.histogram(name="loss",values=loss)
            if(i%5==0):
                print(i, sess.run([W,b])) 
                wb_.append(sess.run([W,b]))

print(writer.get_logdir())
print(writer.close())
```

As the loop runs the line :

```
 s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
```

is giving me error.

I really don't understand why `feed_dict` is present inside the above line.
 What would happen if it is not there ?

Also, why are we passing `s_mer` into add_summary() ? I didn't understand its role. Can't we just pass "summary_merge" into the add_summary().

Please, explain the role of add_summary().

The error I'm getting in my IPython NB is :

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_56' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_56 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-ca71ed6cdb0f> in <module>()
     68 
     69     for i in range(epochs):
---> 70         s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
     71         sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
     72 

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_56' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_56 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder_56', defined at:
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1431, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 117, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2903, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-a13d7623267d>", line 47, in <module>
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,bd.shape[1]-1))
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_56' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder_56 = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that variables `dataset_input` and `dataset_output` are of dtype `float64` but you use for placeholders `float32`, but they need to be same. `dataset_input = np.array(dataset_input, dtype=np.float32)` and `dataset_output = np.array(dataset_output, dtype=np.float32)` helps on my computer.

Then when you are calling `sess.run(loss)` you need to add `feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output}` as well because it uses X and Y placeholders.

> I really don't understand why feed_dict is present inside the above line. What would happen if it is not there ?

You need to use feed_dict to feed data to your placeholders. If you don't provide it with any data then similar errors occurs, because it has no data for your computations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176497/discussion-on-answer-by-paprikadobi-invalidargumenterror-you-must-feed-a-value).