# Parameters shooting to infinity while training after some epochs

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression, tensorboard

I'm implementing Linear Regression in `Tensorflow` first time. Initially, I tried it using a linear model but after few iterations of training, my parameter shot up to infinity. So, I changed my model to a quadratic one and again tried training but still after few iterations of epochs, the same thing is happening.

Hence, the parameter in `tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W0)` is receiving inf as a parameter and similar is the case with W1 and b1.

I wanted to see my parameters in tensorboard(because I've never worked with it) but getting this error.

I have asked the question previously but the slight change was that I was using a linear model which again was giving the same problem(I didn't know that it was due to the parameters going to infinity because I was running this in my Ipython Notebook but when I ran the program in the terminal, the below-mentioned error was generated, which helped me figure out that the problem was due to the parameters shooting to infinity ). In the comments section, I got to know that it was working on someone's PC, and his tensorboard showed that the parameters were actually reaching infinity.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51456408/invalidargumenterror-you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor-placeholder) is the link to the problem asked earlier.
I hope that I've correctly declared Y_ in my program else do correct me!

Here is the code in Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

boston=load_boston()
type(boston)
boston.feature_names

bd=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)

bd['Price']=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.target)
np.random.shuffle(bd.values)


W0=tf.Variable(0.3)
W1=tf.Variable(0.2)
b=tf.Variable(0.1)
#print(bd.shape[1])

tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W0)
tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W1)
tf.summary.histogram('Biases', b)



dataset_input=bd.iloc[:, 0 : bd.shape[1]-1];
#dataset_input.head(2)

dataset_output=bd.iloc[:, bd.shape[1]-1]
dataset_output=dataset_output.values
dataset_output=dataset_output.reshape((bd.shape[0],1)) 
#converted (506,) to (506,1) because in pandas
#the shape was not changing and it was needed later in feed_dict


dataset_input=dataset_input.values  #only dataset_input is in DataFrame form and converting it into np.ndarray


dataset_input = np.array(dataset_input, dtype=np.float32) 
#making the datatype into float32 for making it compatible with placeholders

dataset_output = np.array(dataset_output, dtype=np.float32)

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,bd.shape[1]-1))
Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

Y_=W0*X*X + W1*X + b    #Hope this equation is rightly written
#Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.pow(X, pow_i), W), Y_pred)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)


loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_-Y))
tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)



wb_=[]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    summary_merge = tf.summary.merge_all()

    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("Users/ajay/Documents",sess.graph)

    epochs=10
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(epochs):
        s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X: dataset_input, Y: dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})

        #CHANGED
        sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
        writer.add_summary(s_mer,i)

        #tf.summary.histogram(name="loss",values=loss)
        if(i%5==0):
            print(i, sess.run([W0,W1,b]))
            wb_.append(sess.run([W0,W1,b]))

print(writer.get_logdir())
print(writer.close())
```

I'm getting this error :

```
 /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
(?, 13)
(?, 1)
2018-07-22 02:04:24.826027: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
0 [-3833776.2, -7325.9595, -15.471448]
5 [inf, inf, inf]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Infinity in summary histogram for: Biases
     [[Node: Biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Biases/tag, Variable_2/read)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LR.py", line 75, in <module>
    s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X: dataset_input, Y: dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Infinity in summary histogram for: Biases
     [[Node: Biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Biases/tag, Variable_2/read)]]

Caused by op 'Biases', defined at:
  File "LR.py", line 24, in <module>
    tf.summary.histogram('Biases', b)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 187, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 283, in histogram_summary
    "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3414, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1740, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Infinity in summary histogram for: Biases
     [[Node: Biases = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Biases/tag, Variable_2/read)]]
```

Comment: I've reduced the gradient decent value but still the problem persists.

Comment: The answer below is still not working !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is caused due to high learning rate for Gradient descent.
Please refer [Gradient descent explodes if learning rate is too large](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315664/gradient-descent-explodes-if-learning-rate-is-too-large)

Here the loss is actually getting bigger after each epoch.

I changed

```
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001)
```

to

```
optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0000000001)
```

Then printed the loss after each epoch. By changing

```
sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
```

to

```
print("loss",sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output}))
```

in your code. The error was gone. The output was

```
(?, 13)
(?, 1)
loss =  44061484.0
0 [-0.08337769, 0.19926739, 0.099998444]
loss =  3373030.2
loss =  258605.05
loss =  20211.799
loss =  1964.4918
loss =  567.7717
5 [-0.0001616638, 0.19942635, 0.099998794]
loss =  460.862
loss =  452.67877
loss =  452.05255
loss =  452.00452
Users/ajay/Documents
None
```

Comment: No, it is still giving me the same error and I've already tried your solution before.

Comment: That is strange. Please find the full code here.
https://gist.github.com/SragAR/77c084a6461d5fb821293efa199aed1d

Comment: I fixed the problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872592/invalidargumenterror-you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor-placeholder