# InvalidArgumentError : You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have written the following code in my Jupyter Notebook which does Linear Regression in Tensorflow :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

boston=load_boston()
type(boston)
boston.feature_names

bd=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.data,columns=boston.feature_names)

bd['Price']=pd.DataFrame(data=boston.target)
np.random.shuffle(bd.values)


W0=tf.Variable(0.0000000000003)
W1=tf.Variable(0.000000000002)
b=tf.Variable(0.0000000000001)
    #print(bd.shape[1])

tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W0)
tf.summary.histogram('Weights', W1)
tf.summary.histogram('Biases', b)



dataset_input=bd.iloc[:, 0 : bd.shape[1]-1];
    #dataset_input.head(2)

dataset_output=bd.iloc[:, bd.shape[1]-1]
dataset_output=dataset_output.values
dataset_output=dataset_output.reshape((bd.shape[0],1)) #converted (506,) to (506,1) because in pandas
    #the shape was not changing and it was needed later in feed_dict


dataset_input=dataset_input.values  #only dataset_input is in DataFrame form and converting it into np.ndarray

    # ADDED
dataset_input = np.array(dataset_input, dtype=np.float32)
    # ADDED
dataset_output = np.array(dataset_output, dtype=np.float32)

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,bd.shape[1]-1))
Y=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

Y_=W0*X*X + W1*X + b
    #Y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(tf.pow(X, pow_i), W), Y_pred)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)


loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(Y_-Y))
tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0000000000001)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.global_variables_initializer()#tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)



wb_=[]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    summary_merge = tf.summary.merge_all()

    writer=tf.summary.FileWriter("Users/ajay/Desktop",sess.graph)

    epochs=6
    sess.run(init)

    for i in range(epochs):
        s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X: dataset_input, Y: dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})

            #CHANGED
        print("loss",sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output}))
        #sess.run(loss, feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
        writer.add_summary(s_mer,i)

        tf.summary.histogram(name="loss",values=loss)
        if(i%5==0):
            print(i, sess.run([W0,W1,b]))
            wb_.append(sess.run([W0,W1,b]))

        print(writer.get_logdir())
        print(writer.close())
```

It gives the following error :

```
(?, 13)
(?, 1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1038     try:
-> 1039       return fn(*args)
   1040     except errors.OpError as e:

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(session, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1020                                  feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1021                                  status, run_metadata)
   1022 

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py in __exit__(self, type, value, traceback)
     87             try:
---> 88                 next(self.gen)
     89             except StopIteration:

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status()
    465           compat.as_text(pywrap_tensorflow.TF_Message(status)),
--> 466           pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
    467   finally:

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fdf4bc1529e6> in <module>()
     73 
     74     for i in range(epochs):
---> 75         s_mer=sess.run(summary_merge,feed_dict={X: dataset_input, Y: dataset_output})  #ERROR________ERROR
     76         sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:dataset_input,Y:dataset_output})
     77 

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    980     if final_fetches or final_targets:
    981       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
--> 982                              feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
    983     else:
    984       results = []

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1030     if handle is None:
   1031       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1032                            target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1033     else:
   1034       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feed_dict,

~/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1050         except KeyError:
   1051           pass
-> 1052       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1053 
   1054   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'Placeholder', defined at:
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 486, in start
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 127, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 421, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1431, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/asyncio/events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 117, in _handle_events
    handler_func(fileobj, events)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 276, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 233, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 208, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 537, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2662, in run_cell
    raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2785, in _run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2903, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-67ab0a0aaf1a>", line 44, in <module>
    X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,bd.shape[1]-1))
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1507, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1997, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/ajay/anaconda3/envs/Tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

But when I run this in Terminal it gives the following output :

```
    MacBook-Air:Desktop ajay$ python3 LR.py
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
(?, 13)
(?, 1)
2018-08-16 13:40:30.387637: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
loss 592.02905
0 [1.08720556e-07, 3.084597e-10, 4.6065617e-12]
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
loss 591.9113
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
loss 591.7939
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
loss 591.67664
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
loss 591.5597
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
loss 591.44293
5 [6.502434e-07, 1.8367864e-09, 2.7130916e-11]
Users/ajay/Desktop
None
```

Is my Terminal ignoring something with respect to the PlaceHolder or something else ?
I'm not able to identify the errors related to "Placeholders".

Can anyone explain me how to identify them and when do they most probably occur ?

Also, is there anything related to the datatype in this code

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
```

Comment: Is it possible that your jupyter notebook uses a different python version/environment than your terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can add `tf.reset_default_graph()` as the first line in your code in Jupyter Notebook and check.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Any possible explanation for this ? 
I am not able to find the error involving "Placeholder". Also, how do I know that which "Placeholder" is the error referring to with respect to many Placeholder in the code ?

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/859) is the reason.